# Multivariable calculus question (Existence of partial derivatives)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I want to ask that if given a 2-variable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the antiderivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ have the partial derivative with respect to $y$, and also the antiderivative of $f$ with respect to $y$ have the partial derivative with respect to $x$, then could we have the existence for all partial derivatives of $f$, for all $x$ and $y$ ?

Context: I was trying to solve a function-finding problem in Calculus and then got this problem when proving the differentiable of $f$.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question. Say $F_1(x,y):= \int f(x,y)dx$ and $F_2(x,y):= \int f(x,y)dy$. You are asking does existence of $\partial_y F_1$ and $\partial_x F_2$ imply $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Comment: I want to ask does the existence of ${\partial_x F_1}$ and ${\partial_y F_2}$ imply the existence of ${\partial_x f}$ and ${\partial_y f}$ ?

Comment: $C^{\infty}$ seems to be too much :))

Comment: Since the potential bounds on the indefinite integrals are the same variables as the differentials, the other partials can pass through the integral. That is: $\partial_i \int f(x,y)dx_j = \int\partial_i f(x,y)dx_j$ when $i\neq j$. So if $\partial_i F_j$ exists then the integral is well defined hence so too should be the integrand: $\partial_i f$. I had a similar problem that used "Liebniz' Integration Rule" to calculate partials of integrals that is worth looking into.

Comment: Thank you! That helps me a lot, I forgot about that rule :)))